# DTS :How to migrate HTML data source into SSIS?

Tags: ssis, migration, dts

I need to migrate the DTS (SQL 2000) package into SQL 2008 SSIS.
The DTS package is using HTML file data source and a Transformation task to import the HTML table 
into the SQL table.
I didn't find the HTML data source in the Connection Manager in the SSIS designer.
Does this functionality exist in the SSIS ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is well formed you could try and run it through as xml source; but I suspect that you may run into issues when it wants a schema.

Another option is to create a custom data source script component  to read the file. this would require a little bit of C# knowledge

Good luck

Comment: Thank you. I reconfigured the program (PowerMTA) to generate the file in the XML instead of HTML format, and I am using XML data source.